# IndexError: list index out of range in TensorFlow Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new to tensorflow and I got an error when trying to fit my model.

The error is:

```
  File "D:\Programs\python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 2886, in _flatten_outer_dims
    output_shape = [product, shape[-1]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('housedata.csv', index_col=None)

target = df.pop('Above')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values))

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
```

A few lines from housedata.csv which I use

```
HouseSize,GardenSize,Quality,Age,Location,Above
27,28,37,6,34,1
38,40,21,10,29,1
39,37,16,7,34,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is a simple problem with the code:

`dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values.reshape((-1, 1))))`

is not correct to pass to the fit function, the batch size should be specified, so change it into:

`dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, target.values.reshape((-1, 1)))).batch(batch_size=32)`

---

By the way, a suggestion: don't use `tf.data.dataset`, just use `x`, `y`
you will run into less problems in the future parts of your code.